# Is using advanced constructs (function, new, function calls) in JSON safe?

Tags: json, standards

JSON is a nice way to pass complex data from my server side code to client side JavaScript. For example, in PHP I can write:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var MyComplexVariable = <?= BigFancyObjectGraph.GetJSON() ?>;
    DoMagic(MyComplexVariable);
</script>
```

This is pretty cool, but sometimes you want to pass more than basic date, like dates or even function definitions. There is a simple and straightforward way of doing it too, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var MyComplexVariable = {
        'SimpleProperty' : 42,
        'FunctionProperty' : function()
         {
             return 6*7;
         },
         'DateProperty' : new Date(989539200000),
         'ArbitraryProperty' : GetTheMeaningOfLifeUniverseAndEverything()
    };
    DoMagic(MyComplexVariable);
</script>
```

And this works like a charm on all browsers I've seen so far. But according to [JSON.org](http://www.json.org) such syntax is invalid. On the other hand, I've seen this syntax being used in very many places, including some popular JavaScript frameworks. So...

**Can I expect any problems if I use "unsupported" JSON features like the above? Why is it wrong or not?**

**Added clarification:** If I expected my JSON to be consumed by some unknown 3rd party software, or even a known parser which was not a browser, then such exotics would indeed most likely not work and I would not attempt to embed them. But I'm interested in the case where the JSON code is written directly inside a JavaScript code block that is executed by an Internet browser. Like the examples above.

Answer (score 2):

According to JSON.org, a JSON object only supports the following value members of an object:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/value.gif))</sub>

Since none of these is a function, I would suggest not using it since, as you said, it is not officially supported in the spec.

Besides, what happens when a non-Javascript client (such as a Python program) tries to consume your JSON? How is it going to run your JavaScript code?

Comment: If I used it just for data where the target parser would most likely NOT be a browser, then I'd agree with you. But I'm asking about the scenario where I'm embedding the JavaScript directly in my JavaScript client side code. It will be executed by a browser.